# Redirect print and/or logging to Panel

Tags: python, rich

I have made a small application that uses a Rich to show a Live view in several Panels.
Is there a way to put standard (or rich) `print` statements into a particular panel?
Being able to show logging output in its own dedicated panel would also work.

I feel like this would be a very common use case but I haven't found any documentation. I think the answer could be in using the `Console.capture()` method but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/live.html#print-log

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I found is by utilizing [console protocal](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocol.html) to make a console itself renderable. Here is an example:

```py
from rich.console import Console
import os

class ConsolePanel(Console):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        console_file = open(os.devnull,'w')
        super().__init__(record=True,file=console_file,*args,**kwargs)

    def __rich_console__(self,console,options):
        texts = self.export_text(clear=False).split('\n')
        for line in texts[-options.height:]:
            yield line
```

by adding a `__rich_console__` method to the `Console` class, it can be directly treated as other renderable objects, and you can put it anywhere in your layout.

Here is a simple example with two consoles placed vertically

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
    from rich.layout import Layout
    from rich.live import Live
    import time
    from datetime import datetime
    class Interface():
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            self.console:list[ConsolePanel] = [ConsolePanel() for _ in range(2)]
        
        def get_renderable(self):
            layout = Layout()
            layout.split_column(
                Layout(self.console[0],name='top'),
                Layout(self.console[1],name='bottom',size=6)
            )
            layout.children[0]
            return layout

    db = Interface()
    with Live(get_renderable=db.get_renderable):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            db.console[0].print(datetime.now().ctime()+'='*100)
            db.console[1].print(datetime.now().ctime())
```

Answer (score 1):

I figure out how you can manage to that. First, we need to intercept the stdout process of Rich logger. We start with a class:

```
from collections import deque
class Logger():
    _instance = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.messages = deque(["sa"])
        self.size = 10

    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(class_._instance, class_):
            class_._instance = object.__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
        return class_._instance

    def write(self, message):
        self.messages.extend(message.splitlines())
        while len(self.messages) > self.size:
            self.messages.popleft()

    def flush(self):
        pass
```

which is a Singleton class. We need to pass this class into console API as

```
from rich.console import Console
c = Console(file=Logger(), width=150)
```

with some width. Then, we create a logging handler

```
from rich.logging import RichHandler
r = RichHandler(console=c)
```

This will be our logging handler as

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level="NOTSET", format=FORMAT, datefmt="[%X]", handlers=[r]
)
logger = logging.getLogger("rich")
```

Later on, we need to use our Logger class called somewhere you manage your layout. For me, it is inside a Dashboard class.

```
class Dashboard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log_std = Logger()
    def update(self, new_parameters):
        self.layout["logs"].update(Panel(Text(
            "\n".join(self.log_std.messages), justify="right"), padding=(1, 2),
        title="[b red]Logs",
        ))
```

Each time I call `update` method, it updates my layout.
My layout is more complex, `self.layout["logs"]` where I show the logs.

Answer (score 1):

So I took @Mete Yildirim's answer as inspiration and came up with a slight variation that uses an existing `logging` handler instead of creating a new logger.

The [logging.handlers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/logging/handlers.py) module has a BufferingHandler() that I used for prototyping my solution.  By passing the handler into `rich`, I can snoop its contents and print them into my `rich` Panel without mods to `logging`.

```
LOG_BUFFER_MAX_MSGS = 20

# Set up the main/root logger
main_logger = logging.getLogger()
main_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Instantiate the buffering handler we will watch from within Rich
buffering_handler = BufferingHandler(capacity=LOG_BUFFER_MAX_MSGS)
main_logger.addHandler(buffering_handler)

# Local logger
log = logging.getLogger("rich")


# Create a basic Rich layout
layout = Layout(name="root")

def get_log():
    """
    We call this method from within Rich to snoop the messages
    within the BufferingHandler and put them in a form Rich 
    can display.
    Check the BufferingHandler() source to see how we can access
    its data.
    """
    log_messages = []
    for li in buffering_handler.buffer:
        log_messages.append(li.msg)
    return Panel("\n".join(log_messages))

# Run Rich, displaying each log message to the screen
with Live(layout, refresh_per_second=4) as live:
    while True:
        layout["root"].update(get_log())
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

To test the above, we can generate some log messages in the background:

```
def create_log_messages():
    msgs = (
        "Test message 1",
        "Test message 2",
        "Test message 3",
    )
    for li in msgs:
        log.info(li)
        time.sleep(2)

threading.Thread(target=create_log_messages).start()
```

Shortcomings:
The BufferingHandler() will clear it's buffer when the number of lines exceeds the value passed into its `capacity` argument.
I would prefer that it delete old messages instead, but that will require either overloading the existing BufferHandler() implementation or writing a new Handler.  The BufferHandler() code is short, so simply writing a new one shouldn't be too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I could use print to display and object with the styling from rich but once I put the object in a panel, it wasn't styling it anymore.

Just with print:

```
from rich import print
print(self.model)
```

To solve it, I used pretty printing:

```
from rich import print
from rich.panel import Panel
from rich.pretty import Pretty
prettyModel = Pretty(self.model)
print(Panel(prettyModel))
```

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution violates some rules, but I got logging to work asynchronously. I subclassed `RichHandler` to update a layout instead of printing to stdout. I was not able to figure out how to adjust the vertical cropping or the number of messages to fit the available screen space, so instead, I limited the number of messages to five. Hopefully, someone wiser will pick this up and make it better.

```
class RichHandlerPanel(RichHandler):
    """Send logs to a layout."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        layout: Layout,
        level: Union[int, str] = logging.NOTSET,
        console: Optional[Console] = None,
        panel_title: str = "Log",
        max_display: int = 5,
        **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(level=level, console=console, **kwargs)
        self.layout = layout
        self.full_log = None
        self.panel_title = panel_title
        self.max_display = max_display

    def emit(self, record: LogRecord) -> None:
        """Invoke by logging. This is a copy of the original with a change on how emit is done."""
        message = self.format(record)
        traceback = None
        if (
            self.rich_tracebacks
            and record.exc_info
            and record.exc_info != (None, None, None)
        ):
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = record.exc_info
            assert exc_type is not None
            assert exc_value is not None
            traceback = Traceback.from_exception(
                exc_type,
                exc_value,
                exc_traceback,
                width=self.tracebacks_width,
                extra_lines=self.tracebacks_extra_lines,
                theme=self.tracebacks_theme,
                word_wrap=self.tracebacks_word_wrap,
                show_locals=self.tracebacks_show_locals,
                locals_max_length=self.locals_max_length,
                locals_max_string=self.locals_max_string,
                suppress=self.tracebacks_suppress,
            )
            message = record.getMessage()
            if self.formatter:
                record.message = record.getMessage()
                formatter = self.formatter
                if hasattr(formatter, "usesTime") and formatter.usesTime():
                    record.asctime = formatter.formatTime(record, formatter.datefmt)
                message = formatter.formatMessage(record)

        message_renderable = self.render_message(record, message)
        log_renderable = self.render(
            record=record, traceback=traceback, message_renderable=message_renderable
        )
        if not self.full_log:
            self.full_log = log_renderable
        else:
            for r in range(log_renderable.row_count):
                self.full_log.add_row(
                    *[
                        log_renderable.columns[c]._cells[r]
                        for c in range(len(log_renderable.columns))
                    ]
                )

        while len(self.full_log.rows) > self.max_display:
            for c in range(len(log_renderable.columns)):
                self.full_log.columns[c]._cells.pop(0)
            self.full_log.rows.pop(0)

        try:
            p = Panel(self.full_log, title=self.panel_title, title_align="left")
            self.layout.update(p)
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)
```

When instantiating the handler, I provide the layout cell:

```
    def _init_logging(self) -> None:
        # Handler
        self._log_handler = RichHandlerPanel(
            level=logging.INFO, layout=self.layout["log"]
        )
        # Logger
        self._logger = logging.getLogger()
        self._logger.addHandler(self._log_handler)
```